# Where to include Firebase authentication pre-made UI in Next JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication, next.js, firebaseui

I'm new at React and NextJS but I'd like to use some authentication service for my NextJS web application for managing user accounts.

I'd like to use the pre-made user login we all know and love which contains an all in one solution for logging in with Google, Facebook, Github, email, etc.

[image: login image]

Instructions I've followed:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/firebaseui?authuser=0
- https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebaseui-web/

But I'm having trouble with how to integrate this snippet into my own NextJS code. I'm not sure where to place certain tags.  Here is the code snippet I'd like to emulate which creates a config and passes the object in `ui.start()` (Which I'm not sure where to place for NextJS):

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sample FirebaseUI App</title>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.3/firebase-app-compat.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.3/firebase-auth-compat.js"></script>
    <!-- *******************************************************************************************
       * TODO(DEVELOPER): Paste the initialization snippet from this dialog box:
       * Firebase Console > Project Settings > Add App > Web.
       ***************************************************************************************** -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // FirebaseUI config.
      var uiConfig = {
        signInSuccessUrl: '/',
        signInOptions: [
          // Leave the lines as is for the providers you want to offer your users.
          firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
        ],
        // tosUrl and privacyPolicyUrl accept either url string or a callback
        // function.
        // Terms of service url/callback.
        tosUrl: '/',
        // Privacy policy url/callback.
        privacyPolicyUrl: '/'
        }
      };

      // Initialize the FirebaseUI Widget using Firebase.
      var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
      // The start method will wait until the DOM is loaded.
      ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- The surrounding HTML is left untouched by FirebaseUI.
         Your app may use that space for branding, controls and other customizations.-->
    <h1>Welcome to My Awesome App</h1>
    <div id="firebaseui-auth-container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is what I attempted to integrate the snippet into my NextJS:

#### LoggedIn.js

```js
import Box from '@mui/material/Box'
import {
  GoogleAuthProvider,
  getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'
import app from '../firebase'
import * as firebaseui from 'firebaseui'
import firebase from 'firebase/app'

export default function LoggedIn() {

  return (
    <>
    <script>
      var uiConfig = {
        signInSuccessUrl: '/sandbox/login/signup',
        signInOptions: [
          // Leave the lines as is for the providers you want to offer your users.
          GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
          // FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
        ],
        tosUrl: '/',
        privacyPolicyUrl: '/'
      }

      // Initialize the FirebaseUI Widget using Firebase.
      var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth())
      // The start method will wait until the DOM is loaded.
      ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig)
    </script>
    <Box>
      <h1>Welcome to My Awesome App</h1>
      <Box id="firebaseui-auth-container"></Box>
    </Box>
    </>
  )
}
```

#### I've tried

Looking at some solutions online but they didn't make sense to me or were slightly different from my setup

- https://dev.to/vvo/how-to-solve-window-is-not-defined-errors-in-react-and-next-js-5f97

Comment: As the script is a js script, you can add its code directly in the component without a script tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too hard, I've discovered `StyledFirebaseAuth`

This makes my application work as intended.

```
import StyledFirebaseAuth from "react-firebaseui/StyledFirebaseAuth"
```

Comment: Google one tap login is not working when using this.

Comment: react-firebaseui 6.0.0 does not work with React 18 but there is a solution: https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web-react/pull/173#issuecomment-1215648239